# PowerApp Canvas App for survey/questionanire

Tags: powerapps-canvas, microsoft-forms

I need to build a PowerApp which presents a daily list of tasks to a user such as number of surveys to complete; within which postcode area etc.
They then want to complete a questionnaire; and store submissions in the PowerApps own Dataverse.

My thoughts are;

- Ideally i would want to hook up Microsoft Forms (standard not Pro) so the PowerApp could either link to the form and pre-populate a unique ID or similar? they complete the form; and a Logic App would process into the DataVerse by unique ID. However not sure this is possible?
- Other option is i design the Canvas App to complete the survey (similar to the Employee Engagement survey template) - but likely will have 30/40 questions - this would obviously have a direct link to the Dataverse so no Logic App required
- Other options?

Thanks in advance
Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stay away from Microsoft Forms for a 30-40 question survey. The conditional logic, error handling, input validation, etc are not robust enough. You'd likely get too much free text to produce any meaningful reports from.

**Caveat being:** Do external users (outside your Active Directory) need to access the survey?

- If so, then Forms is likely the only way to go (unless you want to somehow manage PowerApps licenses for external users).

PowerApps will suffice.

Comment: Thanks - yes fortunately internal only - went with PowerApp with SPO datasource (to store questions) and works well!